# C# returning public field from method

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm writing scripts for Unity3D in C# and have a little helper method in one of my classes called `constraintForType` that returns a public field for a certain type like so:

```
public Constraint topConstraint = Constraint.falseConstraint;
public Constraint bottomConstraint = Constraint.falseConstraint;

enum ConstraintType {
    Top,
    Bottom
}

Constraint constraintForType(ConstraintType type) {
    switch(type) {
    case ConstraintType.Top:
        return topConstraint;
    case ConstraintType.Bottom:
        return bottomConstraint;
    }

    return Constraint.falseConstraint;
}
```

I'm calling this method from the `Update` loop but it seems that the constraint that I'm returning is not the same as the public declaration (maybe a copy?).

So in the `Update` loop this would work:

```
void Update() {

    topConstraint.constant = // Calculated value
}
```

But this doesn't:

```
void Update() {

    Constraint con = constraintForType(ConstraintType.Top);
    con.constant = // Calculated value
}
```

I thought maybe the method was returning a copy of the public field so I changed it to:

```
void constraintForType(ConstraintType type, ref Constraint con) {

    switch(type) {
    case ConstraintType.Top:
        con = topConstraint;
        break;
    case ConstraintType.Bottom:
        con = bottomConstraint;
        break;
    }
}
```

So I then call this in the `Update`:

```
Constraint con = Constraint.falseConstraint;
constraintForType(ConstraintType.Top, ref con);
```

This still doesn't work though.

What is going on here?

EDIT:

`Constraint` is a struct.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I'm trying to avoid calling a large `switch` block more than once. Tidy code you know. I've only put two here but the switch is significantly bigger in the actual Script.

Comment: I guess you know there is just one instance?

Comment: What is `Constraint.falseConstraint`?

Comment: It is a static property in the `Constraint` struct that returns a placeholder `Constraint` so I know something went wrong. And yes I thought there must be only one instance which is why I'm confused.

Comment: What type of type is `Constraint`, a struct or a class?

Comment: It is  a struct. Is that the reason?

Comment: Then you're returning a copy.

Comment: You set both topConstraint and bottomConstraint to Constraint.falseConstraint so unless you change them somewhere outside of the code you show, constraintForType always returns Constraint.falseConstraint.

Comment: Is `Constraint` your type or something built into unity?

Comment: They're edited in the Unity interface inspector. The struct is serialisable. How can I return the right struct then? `Constraint` is my type.

Comment: You should never, ever, write mutable structs. Make it a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your Constraint -struct to class. Structs are value types that are (usually) immutable.

Comment: Thank you I've done that. I thought struct might be more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, your first method is returning a copy of the stuct. However, your second version is making a copy as well:

```
void constraintForType(ConstraintType type, ref Constraint con) {

    switch(type) {
    case ConstraintType.Top:
        con = topConstraint; // struct is copied here
        break;
    case ConstraintType.Bottom:
        con = bottomConstraint; // struct is copied here
        break;
    }
}
```

One way to make this work in your case would be to assign inside the helper function

```
void constraintForType(ConstraintType type, Foo constant) {

    switch(type) {
    case ConstraintType.Top:
        topConstraint.constant = constant; 
        break;
    case ConstraintType.Bottom:
        bottomConstraint.constant = constant; 
        break;
    }
}
```

Of course, if you do not have a particular reason to use a mutable struct, use a class instead. [Mutable structs have some difficulties.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/441309/145999)

Comment: Thanks. I've actually changed it to `class` now.

Comment: Probably for the best, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/why-are-mutable-structs-evil